# Is there a name for "Breaking up a line at regular intervals"?

Tags: javascript, line

I have a line in the form of an array of coordinate points:

```
[{x1,y1}, [x2,y2], ect...]
```

The points which make up the line are at varying distances from one another.

My goal is to make a function which takes this line and split it up into evenly separated distances.

All I'm looking for is the terminology for this process... Interpolation? because I want to search for it and not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I don't understand what "split it up into evenly separated distances" means.

Comment: You're going to infer the equation for the line from the points, then you're going to generate points parametrically along the line between the most widely-separated two points.

Comment: Segmenting/Segmentation?

Comment: Is the line straight? Otherwise, it's hard to talk about "breaking up" a line because of the "bends".

Comment: @Jack if it's not straight, then I'm not sure it should be called a "line".

Comment: This sounds more like a math question than a programming question.

Comment: @Pointy Quite right. In which case any combination of two points can be used to deduce the linear function :) so the question should really be how to segment a line given by said function in between two  values of x.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terminology, not programming. Perhaps [EnglishUsage.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/) might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call that segmentation.

First you determine the linear function that defines the line itself; at least two points are required for that.

Afterwards, you need:
1. The above linear function
2. Two values of x that will define the leftmost and rightmost point
3. The segment length, so that the hypothenuse between the endpoints is a multiple of it.

Finally you create a function that takes the above three pieces of data and returns a list of points, evenly separated by given segment length.

Answer (score 0):

More synonyms, if you are just looking for the visual effect, not the actual numeric values, using a graphics API: "dot-dash", "dash-dot", and "dotted and dashed lines".

Will the dashing be at done using the data coordinate space or the output coordinate space?  If data, you might need to enforce a 1:1 graphics display for the dashing to appear consistent vertically and horizontally.